# split cookie and return json array

Tags: java, json, parsing, cookies

I'm making a small application in java. I`m trying return JSON array. but I'm getting error in it, I need to use the cookie I have stored, split it and return it as JSON array.

```
            String json = null; 
            if(json == null)
            {
                //return empty array
                json = "[]";
            }
            else
            {
               //split cookie
               String wl[] = wishList.split("~");

                json += "[";
                   for(int i = 0; i < json.length(); ++i)
                   {
                      json += wl[i];
                   }
                json += "]";
```

Problem is i'm not sure if that's the correct way to return the json array, 
any help will be great. Thank You!

Comment: What's the error you're getting in it?

Comment: I think you mean `i < wl.length`. Also, you will need to escape, quote, and comma separate the tokens. It would be much easier if you used a library like jackson.

Answer (score 0):

I think your program will never run into `else statement` 
as your code below:

```
 String json = null; 
 if(json == null)
 {
    //return empty array
   json = "[]";
 }
```

---

the json will always *"[]"*, *check it again please*.